# Indexing a infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm doing a proof that uses Cantor's diagonal argument, but I need to index an infinite set $X$ without knowing whether the set is countable or not.

I'm thinking like this $X=\{x_i:i \in I\}$ so $f[X]=\{f(x_i):i \in I\}$. Is there a way to write $f[X]$ in a good way to use Cantor's diagonal argument?

Comment: What if you consider a subset of $f(X)$ like  {$f(x_{i_n}):x_{i_n}\in X ,n\in \mathbb{N}$} ? Would it help in your proof?

Comment: I think this solved my problem, thank you

Comment: A subtle thing about Cantor's diagonal is that you don't actually do it on the set in question.  You do it on a countable subset.  Then you prove that the countable subset is incomplete and thus must be a proper subset.  Thus every countable subset is proper.  So the set itself is uncountable.  So don'don't index the set.  Index the subset.

Comment: But to answer you question directly:  it's often done as X={$x_a|a\in A $}.  But bear in mind i) you can NOT list these in any order (so yhis is probably useless for any Canto like argiment) and ii) using "i" implies countable.

Comment: And... $I $ is conventionally used to be  a real interval.  Thus if you use it (which you can) you are stating the set has the cadinality of a real interval.  The set might have a higher cardinality than that.

Comment: @fleablood I've often seen $I$ just denote any index set (the choice of name should be obvious) without any implications on its cardinality. And even if there's a convention for $I$ to denote a real interval (which it might be in certain areas, such as measure theory) that doesn't mean one is "stating that the set has the ca[r]dinality of a real interval", because one can decide to not follow conventions (which are not definitions) for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need indexed sets for Cantor's argument. If $f:X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a function, consider $A= \{x \in X: x \notin f(x) \}$.

Suppose that $A =f(p)$ for some $p \in X$. Then $p \in A$ iff by definition $ p \notin f(p)$ iff $p \notin A$, contradiction. So $A \notin f[X]$ and $f$ is not surjective. And as $|X| \le |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ via the injection $g(x)  =\{x\}$, we have $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ as we cannot have a bijection between them, as the above argument shows...

So please explain what kind of Cantor argument you need. His argument has nothing to do with countability.